# What can cause "missing or corrupted header" in zip file after creating a new entry programatically in c#?

Tags: c#, zip

I am trying to create a zip file and then add 2 new entries (xml and csv file) programmatically in C#. But I successed to write first entry, and after that for some reason it makes my zip file corrupted (more precisely it causes missing or corrupted header).

So when it tries to open already existing zip file in order to write the second entry, an exception is thrown.

Exception thrown:

> 'System.IO.InvalidDataException' in System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll ("End of Central Directory record could not be found.")

```
    if (Path.GetExtension(fileName) == ".zip")
    {
        m_fsOutput = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
        m_zipFile = new ZipArchive(m_fsOutput, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);

        ZipArchiveEntry CSVentry = m_zipFile.CreateEntry(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Test{0}.csv", testCells.ElementAt(0).Test), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        m_fsFileWriter = new StreamWriter(CSVentry.Open());
    }
```

This is where I initialize zip file and `streamWriter` for the first entry. Basically `m_fsFileWriter` is a type of `StreamWriter` and I use this object to write the file in other places.

Comment: It may be that you have to "close" each ZipArchiveEntry after write.  While I don't think this involves opening or closing any files, it could be that closing the entry writes the necessary header files without which would result in a corrupt file.

Comment: @Neil but ZipArchiveEntry object cannot be closed or disposed (it doesn't implement IDisposable)

Comment: See wiki so you understand the zip file structure and what the error message means : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)

Comment: @SardarSardarov My advice to you would be to find a good example of how to write a zip file.  You're probably missing something here.  Though not being an expert in C#, I cannot help you here.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do something similar a few weeks ago.
The code I used was this:

```
List<FileStream> FilesList = new List<FileStream>();
//Add your files
using (var archive = new ZipArchive(outStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var FileStream in FilesList)
    {
        string fileName = "File"+i;
        var fileInArchive = archive.CreateEntry(fileName, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        using (var entryStream = fileInArchive.Open())
        {

            entryStream.Flush();
            FileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
            FileStream.Flush();

        }
        i++;
    }

}
var path = "your path";
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    outStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 

    outStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

FilesList are the streams of the files you want to add to the zip archive.